# reading csv files: list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm supposed to read a CSV file with regards to facebook updates on donald trump. I need to create dictionaries in a list like so :

```
[{'link_name': 'Timeline Photos',
'num_angrys': '7',
'num_comments': '543',
'num_hahas': '17',
'num_likes': '6178',
'num_loves': '572',
'num_reactions': '6813',
'num_sads': '0',
'num_shares': '359',
'num_wows': '39',
'status_id': '153080620724_10157915294545725',
'status_link': 'https://www.facebook.com/DonaldTrump/photos/a.488852220724.393301.153080620724/10157915294545725/?type=3',
'status_message': 'Beautiful evening in Wisconsin- THANK YOU for your incredible support tonight! Everyone get out on November 8th - and VOTE! LETS MAKE AMERICA GREAT AGAIN! -DJT',
'status_published': '10/17/2016 20:56:51',
'status_type': 'photo'},
```

using code. I need to get the first two status updates but when I enter the code I get an error that says, "list index out of range".

here is the code

```
def read_csv(input_file, delimiter=","):
    # your code here
    import csv
    csv_data= []
    with open(filename, "r") as csvfile: 
        for row in csvfile:
            row = row.strip("\n")
            columns = row.split(",")

            dict_row = {"link_name": columns [0],
                        "num_angrys": columns [1],
                        "num_comments":columns[2],
                        "num_hahas": columns [3],
                        "num_loves": columns [4],
                        "num_reactions": columns [5],
                        "num_sads": columns [6],
                        "num_shares": columns[7],
                        "num_wows": columns [8],
                        "status_id": columns[9],
                        "status_link": columns[10],
                        "status_message": columns [11],
                        "status_published": columns[12],
                        "status_type": columns[13]}
            csv_data.append(dict_row)


filename = "../Data/csv_data/trump_facebook.tsv"
status_updates = read_csv(filename, delimiter="\t") 
status_updates[0:2]
```

and this is the error message

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-16-352e8f130d5d> in <module>

 27 filename = "../Data/csv_data/trump_facebook.tsv"
---> 28 status_updates = read_csv(filename, delimiter="\t")
 29 status_updates[0:2]

<ipython-input-16-352e8f130d5d> in read_csv(input_file, delimiter)
  9 
 10             dict_row = {"link_name": columns [0],
---> 11                        "num_angrys": columns [1],
 12                        "num_comments":columns[2],
 13                        "num_hahas": columns [3],

IndexError: list index out of range
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Update: I've solved it with this new code, but printing status_updates [0:2] gets me an output with the headers like so:

```
def read_csv(input_file, delimiter=","):
# your code here
csv_data= []
with open(filename, "r") as csvfile:     
    for row in csvfile:
        row = row.strip("\n")
        columns = row.split("\t")
        dict_row = {"link_name":columns[2],
                    "num_angrys" : columns[14],
                     "num_comments": columns[7],
                    "num_hahas": columns[12],
                     "num_likes": columns[9],
                    "num_loves": columns[10],
                     "num_reactions": columns [6],
                    "num_sads": columns[13],
                    "num_shares": columns [8],
                     "num_wows": columns [11],
                    "status_id": columns [0],
                    "status_link": columns [4],
                   "status_message": columns [1],
                    "status_published": columns [5],
                   "status_type": columns [3],}
        csv_data.append(dict_row)
return csv_data

filename = "../Data/csv_data/trump_facebook.tsv"
status_updates = read_csv(filename, delimiter="\t") 
status_updates[0:2]
```

output:

```
[{'link_name': 'link_name',
'num_angrys': 'num_angrys',
'num_comments': 'num_comments',
'num_hahas': 'num_hahas',
'num_likes': 'num_likes',
'num_loves': 'num_loves',
'num_reactions': 'num_reactions',
'num_sads': 'num_sads',
'num_shares': 'num_shares',
'num_wows': 'num_wows',
'status_id': 'status_id',
'status_link': 'status_link',
'status_message': 'status_message',
'status_published': 'status_published',
'status_type': 'status_type'},
{'link_name': 'Timeline Photos',
'num_angrys': '7',
'num_comments': '543',
'num_hahas': '17',
'num_likes': '6178',
'num_loves': '572',
'num_reactions': '6813',
'num_sads': '0',
'num_shares': '359',
'num_wows': '39',
'status_id': '153080620724_10157915294545725',
'status_link': 'https://www.facebook.com/DonaldTrump/photos/a.488852220724.393301.153080620724/10157915294545725/?type=3',
'status_message': 'Beautiful evening in Wisconsin- THANK YOU for your 
incredible support tonight! Everyone get out on November 8th - and VOTE! LETS 
MAKE AMERICA GREAT AGAIN! -DJT',
'status_published': '10/17/2016 20:56:51',
'status_type': 'photo'}]
```

I can easily replace status_update[0:2] to [1:3] but there has to be a more elegant way to remove the header lines so I don't have to worry about using the 1 index each time I call this function. Appreciate all your help!

Comment: How about using pandas? Only take you 1 line to read the data

Comment: line `columns = row.split(",")` should be `columns = row.split(delimiter)`, but in general you should use [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) (you've even imported `csv`!)

Comment: @Gsk I tried delimiter but then my output shows the error 'nonetype' object is non subscriptable. Yes I know!  But I am not allowed to use csv.reader T_T

Comment: Can you update the code with new output and where you wrote `delimiter`?

Comment: @Gsk I've actually solved it! The problem now is that it prints the header when I print status_update[0:2], I can easily fix it by printing  status_update[1:3] but I'm sure there's a cleaner way to do this so I don't have to remember to print [1: ~] every time I call this function. Releasing the updated code!

Answer (score 1):

What does the csv file looks like. I see that the function call uses delimeter as `\t` but the actual code always uses `,`.

Also you might want to consider the python `csv` module for this work.

Comment: This looks more like a comment than an answer. Maybe try to suggest the solution to his problem and a small usage example of `csv.reader`?

Comment: I'm not allowed to use the csv module!  I have to make my own code

Comment: @Gsk, I would prefer to post as a comment but at the time I don't have enough reputation. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem using this approach:

> ```
>  1. read first string of csv file as header 
>  2. construct mapping "header-row" using `zip()` function
> ```

```
def row_preprocess(row, delimiter='\t'):
    return row.strip('\n').split(delimiter)

def read_csv(path_to_file, delimiter='\t'):
    csv_data = []
    with open(path_to_file, 'r') as f:
        column_values = row_preprocess(next(f), delimiter)
        for row in f:
            row_values = row_preprocess(row, delimiter)
            mapping = dict(zip(column_values, row_values))
            csv_data.append(mapping)
    return csv_data
```